# Change text on start of jQuery sortable

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a jQuery sortable list.  When I begin dragging an item, I want to remove some text while it's being dragged so it only shows the first line while dragging.  For example, I have an ol:

```
<ol>
<li>Here is some text. <span>Here is a bunch of other text</span>
<li>Here is some text also. <span>Here is a bunch of other text as well</span>
</ol>
```

When I begin dragging the first li, I would like it to only show "Here is some text" while dragging.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at the jQuery UI for draggable and sortable?  Here is the [site](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#sortable).  Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes I have. I've tried using the 'start' event and modifying the text there but it doesn't change what is displayed during the sort.